# What is the difference between <name> island and island of <name>?

Tags: difference

I see that both are used and don't know what is the difference.

Comment: There is none: different places simply use different official forms of name.

Comment: Of possible interest at EL&U: *[When to put “River” before or after its name and why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69657)*, and to a lesser extent *[Word order, e.g. in “Hotel California”, “Brothers Quay”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46926)*.